# Accordion via URL inside another div

Tags: jquery

In my project I have one accordion and section 1 is active is ther any way to call **id="comment-50"** from url like http://domain.com/data-for-com/#comment-50

```
<div id="accordion">
  Section 1
  <div id="section1" is active>
    <p> data 1 </p>
  </div>
  Section 2
  <div "comment section">
    <div id="comments" class="commet">
      <ul id="comment-comments-list" class="comment-comments-list">
        <li class="someclass" id="comment-50">
          <article id="comment-50" class="comment-comment-content">
            <div>
              <p> data 2 </p>
            </div> 
          </div>
        </article>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i need a URL to highlight 'comment-50'


for shoot an email: like

A new comment has been posted in a discussion you are following.
"URL"

Comment: Use CSS `:active` selector to select target element and change CSS of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get hash value using

```
var hash =  window.location.hash;
```

then you can use this variable add attribute to the desired element